# RSpec stub throws wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking

I'm try to stub the [Slack gem](https://github.com/aki017/slack-ruby-gem) with the new syntax (old syntax throws the same error):

```
before :each do
    allow(Slack).to receive(:channels_join).and_return(true)
end
```

This line throws `wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)`. Breaking up the line into pieces, it seems like the call to `.to` is throwing the error:

```
a = allow(Slack)
b = receive(:channels_join)
c = b.and_return(true)
a.to(c)
```

Changing the arguments to `.to` didn't change anything:

```
a.to(c, c)
```

throws the same `2 for 1` error.

```
a.to(5)
```

throws a reasonable error: `only the receive or receive_messages matchers are supported with allow(...).to, but you have provided: 5`

Why is the `2 for 1` error being thrown?

Comment: have you tried to stub any instance of the class `Slack`, i;e `allow_any_instance_of(Slack).to receive(:channels_join).and_return(true)`

Comment: Turns out `allow_any_instance_of(Slack::Client)` and `expect_any_instance_of(Slack::Client` fixes this issue. If you'd like to post that as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Glad it worked .. :)

Comment: I recommend you don't use `allow_any_instance_of`.  It has many problems.  We recommend against its use: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-3/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance Instead, see my suggested fix below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have enabled the `verify_partial_doubles` option than RSpec will check if `Slack` responds to `:channels_join` when you stub it.  Unfortunately, `Slack.respond_to?` is [implemented incorrectly](https://github.com/aki017/slack-ruby-gem/blob/v1.1.6/lib/slack.rb#L24-L26):

```
def self.respond_to?(method)
  return client.respond_to?(method) || super
end
```

The problem is that `Object#respond_to?` [accepts two arguments](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F) (and has for years, since at least 1.8.7, if not sooner!), and RSpec passes a 2nd arg, expecting that `respond_to?` will accept two arguments since it is supposed to.

To fix it, you can (temporarily) monkey patch the slack gem:

```
module Slack
  def self.respond_to?(method, include_all=false)
    return client.respond_to?(method, include_all) || super
  end
end
```

This should really be fixed in the slack gem, though, so I'd encourage you to open a PR with the maintainers with this fix.

More broadly, when you run into this kind of error, you can learn more about the problem by passing `rspec` the `-b` (or `--backtrace`) flag, which will print the full backtrace.  In your situation I would have expected it to show both the `respond_to?` call site within RSpec and the line where Slack defines `respond_to?` accepting only one argument.  Then you could look at those lines to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! PR opened and good to know about `-b`.

Comment: I'm upgrading RSpec in a jruby 1.9 app and running into this problem.  I suspect somewhere in JRuby there's a similar bug.  This explanation made it clear to me exactly what to look for.  Now I just need to look for it.